# REGEX the response from python requests

Tags: python, regex

I'm not really good at regex and im trying to get dict style strings from python-requests response. Here is the code snippet from html response [cut]:

```
</div>
        </div>


            <div id="image-canvas-caption" class="a-row">
                <div class="a-column a-span12 a-text-center">
                    <span id="canvasCaption" class="a-color-secondary"></span>
                </div>
            </div>           


        <div class="collections-collect-button"></div>

    </div>

</div></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
maintainHeight = function(){
var mainHolder = document.getElementById("main-image-container");
var imgTagWrapperId = document.getElementById("imgTagWrapperId");
if(mainHolder && typeof mainHolder != 'undefined'){
    var width = mainHolder.offsetWidth;
    var ratio = 0.84;
    var shouldAutoPlay = false;
    var videoSizes = [[262, 445], [294, 500], [323, 550], [356, 606], [399, 679]];

    var containerHeight = width/ratio;
    containerHeight = Math.min(containerHeight, 700);

    mainHolder.style.height = containerHeight + "px";
    if(imgTagWrapperId && typeof imgTagWrapperId !== 'undefined' ){
        imgTagWrapperId.style.height = containerHeight + "px";
    }

    var landingImage = document.getElementById("landingImage");
    var imageHeight = Math.min(containerHeight, 679);
    var imageWidth = Math.min(width, 399);
    if(landingImage){
        landingImage.style.maxHeight = imageHeight + "px";
        landingImage.style.maxWidth  = imageWidth + "px";
    }

    if(shouldAutoPlay){
        if(landingImage){
            var autoPlayWidth=0, autoPlayHeight=0;
            for(var i=0; i < videoSizes.length; i++){
                if( autoPlayWidth < videoSizes[i][0] ){
                    autoPlayWidth = videoSizes[i][0];
                    autoPlayHeight = videoSizes[i][1];
                }
            }
            if( autoPlayWidth > 0 && autoPlayHeight > 0 ){
                var videoRatio = autoPlayWidth/autoPlayHeight;
                // increasing height of the slate image by 1px (and width with the ratio) so that black lines doesn't appear on ipad on right side.
                var isIpad = navigator.userAgent.match(/ipad/i);
                if( isIpad ){
                    containerHeight = containerHeight + 1;
                }
                landingImage.style.width = containerHeight * videoRatio + "px";
                landingImage.style.height = containerHeight + "px";
            }

        }
    }
}
};
maintainHeight();

window.onresize = function(){
maintainHeight();
};
P.when('A').register("ImageBlockATF", function(A){   
var data = {
            'colorImages': { 'initial': [{"hiRes":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/717%2BCE-2hWL._UL1500_.jpg","thumb":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41KLRCK3m%2BL._SR38,50_.jpg","large":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41KLRCK3m%2BL.jpg","main":{"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/717%2BCE-2hWL._UY445_.jpg":[262,445],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/717%2BCE-2hWL._UY500_.jpg":[294,500],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/717%2BCE-2hWL._UY550_.jpg":[324,550],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/717%2BCE-2hWL._UY606_.jpg":[357,606],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/717%2BCE-2hWL._UY679_.jpg":[400,679]}},{"hiRes":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61BabEwSG0L._UL1500_.jpg","thumb":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/2160xHhT4zL._SR38,50_.jpg","large":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/2160xHhT4zL.jpg","main":{"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61BabEwSG0L._UX342_.jpg":[342,95],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61BabEwSG0L._UX385_.jpg":[385,107],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61BabEwSG0L._UX425_.jpg":[425,119],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61BabEwSG0L._UX466_.jpg":[466,130],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61BabEwSG0L._UX522_.jpg":[522,146]}}]}, 
            'colorToAsin': {'initial': {}},
            'holderRatio': 0.84,
            'holderMaxHeight': 700,
            'useStretchyImageFix': true
            };
A.trigger('P.AboveTheFold'); // trigger ATF event.    
return data;
```

});

I only need:

```
'colorImages': { 'initial': [{"hiRes":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/717%2BCE-2hWL._UL1500_.jpg","thumb":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41KLRCK3m%2BL._SR38,50_.jpg","large":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41KLRCK3m%2BL.jpg","main":{"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/717%2BCE-2hWL._UY445_.jpg":[262,445],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/717%2BCE-2hWL._UY500_.jpg":[294,500],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/717%2BCE-2hWL._UY550_.jpg":[324,550],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/717%2BCE-2hWL._UY606_.jpg":[357,606],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/717%2BCE-2hWL._UY679_.jpg":[400,679]}},{"hiRes":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61BabEwSG0L._UL1500_.jpg","thumb":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/2160xHhT4zL._SR38,50_.jpg","large":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/2160xHhT4zL.jpg","main":{"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61BabEwSG0L._UX342_.jpg":[342,95],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61BabEwSG0L._UX385_.jpg":[385,107],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61BabEwSG0L._UX425_.jpg":[425,119],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61BabEwSG0L._UX466_.jpg":[466,130],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61BabEwSG0L._UX522_.jpg":[522,146]}}]}
```

from `var data`. Im not really good at regex, I fail on this. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to regex it. Just do `json.loads` and then you've got an object. https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: no. the response is in html form. i only cut the text from html code

Comment: You're going to need to show more code. It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: How do you pass that JavaScript object (because it's not a valid JSON object) to Python?

Comment: i misled the readers sorry. i need the dict key and value from var data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
('colorImages.*)\S
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/kK4wV4/2)**

[image]

Comment: You can share links to specific regex101 demos using the Version Control section in the left-hand bar ("save regex"/"update regex")

Comment: thank you for your help! i added a bit on your code `'colorImages.*\S\]}'`. thank you again! really helps!